# Dont want to select Listview's First position By default in Custom Adapert

Tags: android, android-listview

In my Code,I am using Custom Adapter to display Listview Items,,But  Listview's First position is selected by default ,But I don't want like that.After My Selection It should high light.I posted my code below.Can any one help me ?

//To Call SelectionIndex Method

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

customAdapetr's Object.SelectionIndex(arg2);    

}
```

//To get Selected Position:

```
public void SelectionIndex(int selectedposition){
        this.selectedposition = selectedposition;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

--

```
getView(){

if (position == selectedposition) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);

        }else {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_palewhite_grad);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the activity/adapter is getting initialized, selectedposition has a value of '0' (zero) which is causing the first item to be selected.

Try declaring the selectedposition to be -1 (any negative value)